# Создание библиотеки на C#

Tags: c#, библиотеки

Здравствуйте! Я только начал учиться писать библиотеки и тут у меня возник такой вопрос: если я в своей библиотеке буду использовать пространство имен System, я не смогу получается использовать свою библиотеку там, где нет этого файла? Просто, если, допустим мне нужно использовать какие то мат.функции, надо самому писать все с нуля или можно как то по другому?

Comment: Пространство имен и имя файла никак не связаны. Конечно если на целевой машине нет библиотеки с нужным кодом, то оно работать не будет. Но то, что входит в поставку дот.нет точно будет на целевой машине. А в случае .net core будет в поставке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все  просто, есть библиотеки, которые идут с .NET Framework. Пространство имен System входит в mscorlib, и, соответственно, всегда есть так, где есть .NET Framework.

Спокойно используйте.

Так же, хотелось бы отметить, что сторонние библиотеки, подключаемые через NuGet, обычно всегда копируются в выходной каталог приложения (или библиотеки), и распространяются вместе в ним (ней).

Если вы подключаете свою библиотеку, обязательно поставьте ей копирование в выходной каталог, вот и все.

Конкретно про математические функции - если это стандартные функции из System.Math, то они так же входят в mscorlib, который всегда ставится вместе с фреймворком.

Другой разговор, если вы их подключаете из какой-то библиотеки - пару абзацев выше я отметил такой случай.